# from xml to objects and then to my database

Tags: spring, eclipselink, jaxb2

i'm working on parsing xml documents and stroring the parsed elements into database therefore i'm using jaxb to unmarsh the xml and eclipseLink to map the result ( objects created from the xml ) into my dbase. But i dont know how to integrate this with Spring because i'have to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following links may help:

**[EclipseLink JPA](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/jpa.php) and Spring**

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/JPASpring

**[EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) and Spring**

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/Spring

**Mapping JPA Entities with EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JPA